# matplotlib histogram issues - xticks and excess space in charts

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, font-size

I am having a couple issues plotting subplots in Matplotlib:

1. I can't get the x-axis tick labels to show up on my top 2 charts. In my code below, I haven't once specified the subplots to share x-axis or anything.
   I've also tried this with `plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)` as well, but it doesn't change the lack of x-axis labels one bit.

   ```
   plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [0,0], 2, 2)
   ax = firstperiod.megaball.plot(kind='hist', bins = 25)
   plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True) 
   plt.xticks(range(0,26,5), range(0,26,5), rotation="horizontal")
   plt.title('Megaball Distrib \'96 - \'99')
   plt.ylabel("# of draws", fontsize = 10)
   ```

I've noticed that if I plot just the top left histogram, the x-axis ticks actually show up, but disappear as soon as I plot more.

[image]

I've tried adjusting tight_layout as well, `plt.tight_layout(w_pad = 2, h_pad = 2)`, but that doesn't help show my x-axis tick values.

2. subplot seems to leave extra space in some of the charts on the right hand side. How do I get rid of that space and use the whole x-axis for my histogram?

Here is what it the whole thing looks like as is.

[image]

Why are some of the x-axis ticks automatically showing up, and some not? And why do my charts have so much extra space? This isn't an issue when I made a bar chart instead of a histogram... (notice that I've tried adjusting `hspace` and `wspace` in `subplot_adjust` as well).

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Distribution of MegaBall Draws', fontsize=20)

plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [0,0], 2, 2)
ax = firstperiod.megaball.plot(kind='hist', bins = 25)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True) 
plt.xticks(range(0,26,5), range(0,26,5), rotation="horizontal")
plt.title('Megaball Distrib \'96 - \'99')
plt.ylabel("# of draws", fontsize = 10)

plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [0,2], 2, 2)
secondperiod.megaball.plot(kind='hist', bins = 36)
plt.xticks(range(0,36,5), range(0,41,5), rotation="horizontal")
plt.title('Megaball Distrib \'99 - \'02')
plt.ylabel("# of draws", fontsize = 10)

plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [2,0], 2, 2)
thirdperiod.megaball.plot(kind='hist', bins = 52)
plt.xticks(range(0,55,5), range(0,55,5), rotation="horizontal")
plt.title('Megaball Distrib \'02 - \'05')
plt.ylabel("# of draws", fontsize = 10)

plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [2,2], 2, 2)
fourthperiod.megaball.plot(kind='hist', bins = 46)
plt.xticks(range(0,50,5), range(0,50,5),rotation="horizontal")
plt.title('Megaball Distrib \'05 - \'13')
plt.ylabel("# of draws", fontsize = 10)

plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [4,1], 2, 2)
fifthperiod.megaball.plot(kind='hist', bins = 15)
plt.xticks(rotation="horizontal")
plt.title('Megaball Distrib \'13 - ')
plt.ylabel("# of draws", fontsize = 10)

plt.tight_layout(w_pad = 2, h_pad = 2)
plt.subplots_adjust(top = 0.8, wspace = 0.75, hspace = 2.5)
plt.savefig("megaball_distribs.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer it for you (`xlabel()` and `ylabel()`)? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12444777/1716866

Comment: What do you mean with x-axis label? Do you mean xlabel? ... I don't see any ... Do you mean the size of the xticklabels? Or is the range of the x-axis not consistent for the different plots? Please be more specific!

Comment: I agree with @plonser: Your question is unclear. And in the image you posted all font sizes seem to be consistent.

Comment: @plonser  - adjusted my question, any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: When I use `plt.plot(...)` instead of  `firstperiod.megaball.plot` it works for me, the xticklabels appear as expected. So, is there something odd in your member function `plot`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083051/matplotlib-xticks-not-lining-up-with-histogram

Answer (score -2):

You can adjust the font size with the bizarrely named `fontsize` parameter.

```
plt.title('Megaball Distrib \'96-99', fontsize = 12)
```

Comment: um, not looking for title size adjustment, looking for axis label adjustments...@maxymoo

Comment: what do you mean x axis font sizes? they all look the same to me. do you mean the number of ticks?

Comment: adjusted my question - hopefully it's clearer this time around!